# NgRx Reducer props value is always undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an effect that returns the data correctly, I am calling an action with the data from an effect but the reducer "detailsList" is always undefined.

Effect calls CustomAction.ShowDetails(props Data)

Effect

```
response.student.details always has data so the response is correct

if (response === "test") {
      return of(CustomAction.ShowDetails(response.student.details));
    }
```

Reducer

```
export interface StudentState {
  newStudentDetails: any[];
}

export const studentInitialState: StudentState = {
  newStudentDetails: null;
};

const reducer = createReducer(
  studentInitialState,
  on(CustomAction.ShowDetails, (state, { detailsList}) => ({
    ...state,
    newStudentDetails: detailsList
  })),

);

export function createStudentReducer(
  state: StudentState,
  action: Action
) {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

detailsList is always undefined

Action

```
export const ShowDetails = createAction(
  CustomActionTypes.ShowDetails,
  props<{ detailsList: any[] }>()
);
```

When I am debugging the reducer, detailslist is always undefined. Any Ideas?

Comment: `return of(CustomAction.ShowDetails(response.student.details));`... concerning the `of` operator, are you inside `switchMap`, `mergeMap`... I mean, an operator that maps the input to another observable?

Comment: @julianobrasil yes, under switchMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this in your effect:

```js
return of(CustomAction.ShowDetails({detailsList: response.student.details}));
```